# image maven:3.8.1-openjdk-11-slim need to have python 3 : image size going up to 800MB

Tags: python, image, docker, maven

For an application using base image : maven:3.8.1-openjdk-11-slim
and some application level deployment - total size of image is around 415MB

But needed python in that as well added with :
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo "Y" | apt-get install python3 python3-pip

..adding some more dev tools which require python (not more then 2 MB size)

but Image size is going to 850MB which high..
Can any one suggest other way to get python on maven base image, with less size

Comment: This based image contains JDK, Maven plus supplemental parts which are needed... The question is why do you need python? In Java dev?

Comment: @khmarbaise need python in java dev to establish connectivity databricks spark based runtime through databricks CLI

Comment: have you analysed via dive which layer added some many things? I bet the layer with `apt-get update...` you should also remove the caches which are generated during `apt-get update` and also after `apt-get install python3...`...